# Uploading files onto rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload

I am working on a CMS app using Rails and I was wondering if someone could guide me or link me to some tutorials that show how to how to attach files to a record? For example, I have a model called Contract. I need to upload various pdf's, word files, spreadsheets, etc. that are associated with that Contract. I then need to be able to download those files. I also need to be able to lock them for editing. I'm not necessarily looking for step by step instructions, but a nudge in the right direction would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for this (although `Carrierwave` also works well):

```
#app/models/contract.rb
Class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :attachment
   validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Apdf\/.*\Z/
end
```

This allows you to populate an object with the required attachment you want like so:

```
#app/views/contracts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @contract do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It must be noted that `Paperclip` or `Carrierwave` don't actually handle the files themselves. They simply provide a *way* to upload them to your server. Both gems basically create an object on top of your "parent" one, allowing you to reference the files contained inside